# How to test my responsive website for screen widths below 500px using Chrome on a desktop machine?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

This is my first time designing a responsive website. I am trying to do a break point of `max-width` of `480px`, but Google Chrome does not allow me to resize the window below 500px. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: **To close-voters:** This is not General Computing. The ability to have the browser display content using an arbitrary screen width is *definitely* a programming tool. While the question could be reworded to be more clear, what's being asked is to have the ability to test their HTML/CSS at various display widths, it explicitly states that the reason they want to do this is directly related to testing the HTML/CSS which they've written. Yes, saying "resize chrome browser" makes it sound like it might be General Computing, but that's because the OP doesn't know the term "responsive design mode".

Answer (score 3):

For this you need to inspect(ctrl+shift+i) your html and click on the highlighted icon as shown here: [image]

[image]

Comment: Is this the inspect element? I guess this is the only way to do it.... Because on the whole, everything looks almost the same but not sure why one of my images is just slightly bit off

Comment: I used the ipad inspect element and just looks a bit off compared to my break point